# How to upload picture while using react-simple-chatbot?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the react-simple-chatbot library to create a chatbot, and would like to allow the user to upload a photo that will later be sent in an email. I've been trying to figure out the best way to go about doing this. Is there a way to set the user input type to accept pictures/files? Or should I set up a system for the user to email the picture, and then somehow read the email on the backend and store it?

Or is there another solution that would be better? Preferably I need a method that can scale with a minimal cost, since I may end up with tens of thousands of images stored.